# LVDS connect Issue. ( If VGA connect. LVDS off )

Tags: xorg, external-monitor, vga

I have very hard problem.

And I don't solute haven't found a solution for this problem while for 3 weeks.

Now tested OS ( ubuntu 14.04, ubuntu 12.10, ubuntu 12.04) same problem.

Physical connected VGA and LVDS. But if VGA connected, LVDS screen off.

I don't now why this problem.

somebody help

CPU :

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz
```

OS :

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"
```

Grapic card :
   $ lspci

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

BIOS VGA setting :

```
- On-chip Frame buffer Size : 8MB
- DVMT Mode : BOTH
- DVMT/FIXED Memory Size 128MB
- Boot Display CRT+LCD(24bit)
- Panel Number 800x600 24/1
```

X info :
    1. Version :

```
X.Org X Server 1.13.0
Release Date: 2012-09-05
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-54-generic i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux lotto-desktop 3.5.0-51-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 21:19:44 UTC 2014 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-51-generic root=UUID=01ccefaf-b010-4a6b-a11c-717305a70dc0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 05 November 2013  03:14:52PM
```

```
2. Configure :
    $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
        FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
        Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"                  # []
        #Option     "kmsdev"                    # 
        #Option     "ShadowFB"                  # []
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "modesetting"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"                   # []
        #Option     "AccelMethod"               # 
        #Option     "Backlight"                 # 
        #Option     "DRI"                       # []
        #Option     "ColorKey"                  # 
        #Option     "VideoKey"                  # 
        #Option     "Tiling"                    # []
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"         # []
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"           # []
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"           # []
        #Option     "HotPlug"                   # []
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"            # []
        #Option     "XvMC"                      # []
        #Option     "Throttle"                  # []
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"               # 
        #Option     "DelayedFlush"              # []
        #Option     "TearFree"                  # []
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"            # []
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"             # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"         # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"          # []
        #Option     "DebugWait"                 # []
        #Option     "BufferCache"               # []
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"              # []
        Identifier  "Card1"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"                   # []
        #Option     "AccelMethod"               # 
        #Option     "Backlight"                 # 
        #Option     "DRI"                       # []
        #Option     "ColorKey"                  # 
        #Option     "VideoKey"                  # 
        #Option     "Tiling"                    # []
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"         # []
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"           # []
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"           # []
        #Option     "HotPlug"                   # []
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"            # []
        #Option     "XvMC"                      # []
        #Option     "Throttle"                  # []
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"               # 
        #Option     "DelayedFlush"              # []
        #Option     "TearFree"                  # []
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"            # []
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"             # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"         # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"          # []
        #Option     "DebugWait"                 # []
        #Option     "BufferCache"               # []
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"              # []
        Identifier  "Card2"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"                  # []
        #Option     "Rotate"                    # 
        #Option     "fbdev"                     # 
        #Option     "debug"                     # []
        Identifier  "Card3"
        Driver      "fbdev"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"                  # []
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"            # []
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"        # []
        Identifier  "Card4"
        Driver      "vesa"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card1"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        Defaultdepth 24
        SubSection "Display"
                Modes "800x600"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen1"
        Device     "Card1"
        Monitor    "Monitor1"
        Defaultdepth 24
        SubSection "Display"
                Modes "800x600"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

```
3. xrandr output : LVDS1 connected, VGA1 non-connected
```

```
$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 600, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x41
    Timestamp:  1940078
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     LVDS1
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
LVDS1 connected 800x600+0+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  1940078
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     VGA1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  800x600 (0x45)   40.0MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x46)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x47)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0x48)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  1940078
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    bottom margin: 37 (0x00000025)  range:  (0,100)
    right margin: 46 (0x0000002e)   range:  (0,100)
    top margin: 36 (0x00000024) range:  (0,100)
    left margin: 54 (0x00000036)    range:  (0,100)
    mode:   NTSC-M
        supported: NTSC-M       NTSC-443     NTSC-J       PAL-M       
                   PAL-N        PAL          480p         576p        
                   720p@60Hz    720p@50Hz    1080i@50Hz   1080i@60Hz
```

```
4. xrandr output : Now physical LVDS1 connected, VGA1 connected
```

```
$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    Identifier: 0x41
    Timestamp:  9242568
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     LVDS1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff004c2e9a303e593f1e
        2f1401030e351c782a3581a656489a24
        1250542308008100814081809500a940
        b30001010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e792e401062842030
        70981300bbf91000001c000000fd0038
        4b1e5f12000a202020202020000000fc
        004c4344204d4f4e49544f520a200068
  1920x1080 (0x45)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1600x1200 (0x46)  162.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock   75.0KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock   60.0Hz
  1680x1050 (0x47)  146.2MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
  1600x900 (0x48)  119.0MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1712 end 1864 total 2128 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x49)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1440x900 (0x4a)  106.5MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock   59.9Hz
  1280x960 (0x4b)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock   60.0KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x800 (0x4c)   83.5MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock   59.8Hz
  1024x768 (0x4d)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x4e)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x4f)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0x50)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
LVDS1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  9242568
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:     VGA1
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  9242568
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    bottom margin: 37 (0x00000025)  range:  (0,100)
    right margin: 46 (0x0000002e)   range:  (0,100)
    top margin: 36 (0x00000024) range:  (0,100)
    left margin: 54 (0x00000036)    range:  (0,100)
    mode:   NTSC-M
        supported: NTSC-M       NTSC-443     NTSC-J       PAL-M       
                   PAL-N        PAL          480p         576p        
                   720p@60Hz    720p@50Hz    1080i@50Hz   1080i@60Hz
```

```
5. Log :
    I think this line very strange. Why disconnected LVDS?
```

```
[    10.813] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 connected
[    10.813] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 disconnected
[    10.813] (II) intel(0): Output TV1 disconnected
```

```
    If you need to all log. I will post that. that's very long.
```

Comment: To avoid some confusions: "LVDS connected, VGA non-connected" is not the output of xrandr, right? Are there four names for the screens (VGA, VGA1, LVDS, LVDS1), or just two? Only two, and the descriptions leave out the number? (Good description, by the way!)

Comment: Volker Sieqel. That's good question. I think port number is not important. but to avoid confusion modify that description. and so output port naming is according to graphic driver. How to setup a dual monitor reference by this site : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution